# Android & OOP - Global Variables vs Inherited Getters in Fragments

Tags: java, android, performance, oop, design-patterns

In a Fragment should you call getActivity() each time you need a reference to the activity or create a global variable 'mActivity' and use this.

Basically you already have an Activity object (getActivity()) and it feels like creating a global (mActivity) is code duplication and creating an extra reference that is unneeded.
**But** also using getActivity() everywhere looks horrid and feels wrong doing multiple method call's each time (performance?).

```
 // Pseudo Android
 public class MyFragent extends Fragment {

      private Activity mActivity; // Global

      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b){

          mActivity = getActivity();

      }

      public void onClick(View v){

         randomMethodTakingActivity(mActivity);
         // or
         randomMethodTakingActivity(getActivity());

      }

      private void someMethod(){
         randomMethodTakingActivity(mActivity);
         // or
         randomMethodTakingActivity(getActivity());
      }

      private void anotherMethod(){
         mActivity.someCallback();
         // or
         getActivity().someCallback();
      }

 }
```

This would also be relevant for getApplication() or getView();

I've read through [Coding for Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html) but can't see anything relevant. I'd like some feedback on the OO nature and also performance (though probably negligible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In a Fragment should you call getActivity() each time you need a reference to the activity or create a global variable 'mActivity' and use this.

Call `getActivity()`. For starters, if you are using `setRetainInstance(true)`, your alternative approach is simply wrong -- you will be pointing to the wrong `Activity` after a configuration change.

> it feels like creating a global (mActivity) is code duplication and creating an extra reference that is unneeded

Absolutely.

> using getActivity() everywhere looks horrid

You are certainly welcome to your opinion.

> feels wrong doing multiple method call's each time (performance?)

If you will be calling it a million times in a tight loop, create a local variable for a temporary cache. Otherwise, the performance hit should not be material.

Or, another way of looking at it, if Traceview says you're spending too much time calling `getActivity()`, then worry about it.

Comment: Can see the benefit now of getActivity() for orientation change. Do you have any opinion on getView()? , tbh will probably now do method call's for them all for conistency, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Blundell: "Do you have any opinion on getView()?" -- generally, I use the built-in methods unless I have a clear and present reason to do otherwise (e.g., the million-pass loop).

Comment: 'Otherwise, the performance hit should not be material.' That's it !!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about GOF(Gang of Four) Design pattern? 
I think your problem are solved already in Factory method Pattern.

Comment: I don't think the Factory Design Pattern is relevant here. What would you expect to pass in to a Factory? And then return the Application?